How to add Choices/Options dynamically in a Dropdown attribute in Power Apps?
I'm using JavaScript code(triggered by a button) to create a column in 'Opportunity' Table. Now, I want to add options to a column(datatype is Choice) dynamically. Can you please tell me how can I achieve that?
Line of Command used to create Column - var apiUrl = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='" + entityName + "')/Attributes";
I tried calling the same API, using PATCH Method, but it fails saying - "Error adding options to the attribute: The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'."
Power Apps Screenshot
Note: Please share your though if there are any other ways to achive this?
